# Destroying and creating Highstock chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm wondering why this below snippet isn't working:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', config);
$('#container').highcharts().destroy();
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', config);
```

If you comment out the last two lines, the chart appears. But the second time I try to render a chart to the same element (third line), only the title appears. What's going on?

This snippet above tells me I can't render a chart to an element, then render a different chart in the same place, later?

In my application, I have a single element that shows a chart. There's an `<select>` that allows the user to change which chart they want to see. I want to render the new chart to the same element as the previous chart.

Here's a sandbox: http://jsfiddle.net/82ajq3f6/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your config.series is getting nuked when you destroy the chart. I am not sure why. To keep your chart [options](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.options) functioning you can do:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', config);
var opts = $('#container').highcharts().options;
$('#container').highcharts().destroy();
$('#container').highcharts(opts);
```

Comment: Ah, you're right. This works: 
        `var configCopy =  $.extend({},config);
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', config);
        $('#container').highcharts().destroy();
        $('#container').highcharts(configCopy);`